# Find change of speed

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let the temperature of a point in the $xy$-plane be given by $T(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. What is the speed of temperature change in point $(1,5)$ in direction that makes a $30^\circ$ angle with the positive part of the $x$-axis ?

I have tried using vector calculus, but didn't make any result at the end? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: We have no time variable in this problem. If you wanted an actual *rate* of change with respect to time, you'd need to know at what speed you're moving in that direction at that moment. If this problem is from a textbook, it's bad.

Answer (score 0):

$$\Delta T=\Delta x\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}|_{1,5}+\Delta y\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}|_{1,5}$$
$$\frac{\Delta T}{\Delta s}=\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta s} \frac{\partial T}{\partial x}|_{1,5}+\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta s} \frac{\partial T}{\partial y}|_{1,5}=\cos\theta\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}|_{1,5}+\sin\theta\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}|_{1,5}$$